# Unexpected result of the function (recursion)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to implement the function which creates a list from arguments that are passed to the function.

Here's my code:

```
(defun lstbuilder (&rest args)
  (if (eq (car args) NIL)
      NIL
      (cons (car args)
            (lstbuilder (cdr args)))))
```

This function doesn't work correctly.
Results:

```
(lstbuilder 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e) ;expected (a b c d e)
(a (b c d e)) ;result
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not implementing it in the simpler way of `(defun lstbuilder (&rest args)
  args)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `(apply #'lstbuilder (cdr args))` in order to "splat" the list's contents as the function call arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how to return this list from the function?

Comment: "The incoming list for &rest arguments is already a freshly allocated list."  Actually, it's *not* necessarily a freshly allocated list.  The value of the &rest argument of a function called with APPLY can share structure with the list argument to APPLY.  Specifically, the [HyperSpec for APPLY](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm) says:

Comment: "When the function receives its arguments via &rest, it is permissible (but not required) for the implementation to bind the rest parameter to an object that shares structure with the last argument to apply. Because a function can neither detect whether it was called via apply nor whether (if so) the last argument to apply was a constant, **conforming programs must neither rely on the list structure of a rest list to be freshly consed, nor modify that list structure.**"

Comment: @Joshua Thanks! I'll remove that comment then.

Comment: In LispWorks, this happens: `(let* ((a (list 1 2 3))
       (b (apply #'my-list a)))
  (setf (car a) 42)
  a)
;=> (42 2 3)`

Comment: @Joshua That's awesome. That behaviour is not permissible in Scheme (for better or worse).

Comment: Just for reference, here's the part of R5RS that says the list is always freshly allocated. In [4.1.4 Procedures](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.1.4): "syntax:  (lambda <formals> <body>)  ... <Formals> should have one of the following forms: ... (<variable1> ... <variablen> . <variablen+1>): ... **The value stored in the binding of the last variable will be a newly allocated list** of the actual arguments left over after all the other actual arguments have been matched up against the other formal arguments. "

Answer (score 5):

**Style**

- Please use standard Lisp formatting. Use an editor will help you to indent Lisp code.
- Don't put a parenthesis alone on a line. This just wastes space without benefit.
- Longer names get a `-` between the words: `list-builder`.
- Don't use `car`and `cdr` for list operations. Use `first` and `rest`.
- The end of list test is `endp`.

Example:

```
(defun list-builder (&rest args)
  (if (endp args)
      nil
    (cons (first args)
          (apply #'list-builder (rest args)))))
```

Since the `args` variable is already a list, we can just copy it:

```
(defun list-builder (&rest args)
  (copy-list args))
```

Or we can just reuse the `list` function, which already creates a list of its args:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'list-builder)
      #'list)
```

Comment: Minor nitpick, I think the if is indented according the elisp style not common lisp, with the consequent with more indentation.

Comment: @PuercoPop: actually this is the default indentation style in LispWorks.

Comment: I didn't knew that. I wonder why, in elisp it is because the else clause is wrapped in an outer progn so that was the justification

Comment: @PuercoPop: maybe it gives a bit more visual clue. Btw., in Zmacs one can indent and then rotate through several indentation alternatives.